# Nginx - Redirect requests to all backends

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I have 5 backend servers. I want nginx to forward the POST request for /myapp/refresh to all 5 backend servers. For any other request, it can do load balancing. Is this possible ? Can you please give a sample configuration ?

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware about ready to use solution to do what you want.

It is definetely possible to implement such behavior in C or Lua.

You may develop nginx C module, but it not trivial task with serious learning curve.

You may use https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module and use something like https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture_multi.

But in both cases you should implement some kind of logic when and which response you will send back.

Question to think about - do you need to respond with 200 OK if one of the backend will time out or responds with error?

Answer (score 1):

You can try use the The ngx_http_mirror_module module (1.13.4), this implements mirroring of an original request by creating background mirror subrequests. Responses to mirror subrequests are ignored. https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mirror_module.html

Comment: Have you tested?

Comment: I have tested with nginx:1.17.8 and multiple mirror directives seems to make multiple subrequests instead of load balancing.

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to use nginx as a load balancer using a simple config such as:

```
http {
  upstream myproject {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000 weight=3;
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    server 127.0.0.1:8002;
    server 127.0.0.1:8003;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://myproject;
    }
  }
}
```

docs:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/load-balancer/

This should route all requests including the POST request you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. But I want only that particular POST to go to all servers...other requests should be served by only one backend server. Does the above configuration work like that ?